# Not able to change Connection String in SSIS DTSX package

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, ssis

I have 2 SSIS(DTSX) packages which is existing one made in SQL Server 2008,
Now I Have to migrate into SQL server 2012 But I am getting problem in changing connection string .
When I open in the Designer mode using SQL Server Data Tools. Previously it was pointing to another Remote Server Now I am not able to change the new server,
I am using the Provider as-Native OLEDB/Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server,
Server Name when I am giving automatically it's not coming in the dropdown list and when I check Test Connection it is giving Test Connection Succeeded but when I click Ok it is not changing?

Can anyone please help me on this to Resolve this problem

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

The connection might be being set by an expression. Check the expressions for that connection - you may have to change the expression that is being used to set the connection.